# Possible to control PDF layout with iText?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I'm writing some logic to build a large single PDF file that our users can print at their convenience. I'm using Java's iText library (through Clojure's clj-pdf).

I'm trying to have the PDF show the same exact template form on every single page, however I can't seem to find any documentation or indication that one can have PDF content "fit to a page".

The text in these forms varies a little bit, so there's a chance it might require more of fewer text lines per page. This means that the content has a chance of spilling over to the next page, or being too short, making the next page creep up into the previous one, breaking the requirement of "one form per page" for the rest of the document.

I'm trying to figure out if my option is pretty much only to manually check the length of the text on each page and potentially crop it by hand if I goes over n lines, or if the PDF format somehow supports a smart way of having paragraphs+tables+headings all fit in one page. Some UI systems allow you to control how spill-over is handled, anywhere from cropping to resizing the font, so I'm curious if PDF supports anything of that sort.

Edit: ended up going with pagebreaks for simplicity, wasn't aware of that option when I wrote this question.

Comment: you state pdf supports it ... i think you mean the application i select to create pdf supports it. and as you also state, there are many ways to contol a spill from cropping to font size to line spacing to paragraph spacing ... if you are specifying iText as you solution then you can program all of these.if you are using an alternative solution like xsl fo, then they may be in the product you choose. given what you asked, you need to program it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take control over the space taken by text, for instance to fit it on a single page, the way to go would be to create a `ColumnText` object and to add the content in *simulation mode*. If the text fits the page, add it for real. If it doesn't, use a smaller font size. This is demonstrated in the [MovieAds](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=163) example where snippets of text are fitted into AcroForm fields.